# How to configure Burp Suite Community v1.7.36 to capture both http and https traffic on Windows 8?

Tags: security, proxy, windows-8, capture, burp

How to configure Burp Suite Community v1.7.36 to capture both http and https traffic?

Test Environment:

- **OS**: Windows 8 Pro
- **Browser**: Google Chrome v68.0
- **Burp Proxy**: burpsuite_community_windows-x64_v1_7_36.exe

Followed the @PortSwigger's amazing [video](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783055-Installing_Configuring%20your%20Browser.html) to configure the Browser to work with Burp as follows:

- Burp Configuration Snapshot:

[image: Proxy_Options]

- The browser configuration includes settings for `HTTP`, `Secure` and `FTP`.
- Browser Proxy Settings Snapshot:

[image: Proxy_Settings]

Now when I am manually trying to invoke invoke a **http** based *url* e.g. `http://testng.org/doc/maven` Proxy is properly intercepting the `http GET` request and I can capture the following:

```
GET /doc/maven.html HTTP/1.1
Host: testng.org
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://testng.org/doc/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: __utmz=37447461.1527604986.1.1.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmcct=/|utmcmd=referral; __utmc=37447461; __utma=37447461.2068459366.1527604986.1535975911.1535984412.9; __utmb=37447461
Connection: close
```

But when I am trying to invoke a **https** based *url* e.g. `https://www.facebook.com/` I am facing the **Your connection is not private** page.

[image: https_facebook_com]

Though the *Browser Configuration* includes settings for `HTTP` and `Secure` are there any other configuration needed to access the `https` enabled sites?

Comment: You need to [Install Burp's certificate in your browser](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783075-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-your-browser)

Comment: @PortSwigger Thanks a lot for the comment/link. Now able to intercept the HTTPS traffic as well. Would you like to publish this comment as an answer for the benefit of the future readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PortSwigger's comment was in the right direction solving the issue.

To configure *Burp Suite Community v1.7.36* to capture both `http` and `https` traffic you need to install Burp's certificate in your browser following the [documentation](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783075-installing-burp-s-ca-certificate-in-your-browser).

### Steps

- Configure your browser to use Burp as its proxy, and configure Burp's Proxy listener to generate CA-signed per-host certificates (this is the default setting). Then use the links below for help on installing Burp's CA certificate in different browsers:
- [Chrome](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783085-Installing_Installing%20CA%20Certificate%20-%20Chrome.html)

  - The Chrome browser picks up the certificate trust store from your host computer. By installing Burp's CA certificate in your computer’s built-in browser (e.g. Internet Explorer on Windows, or Safari on OS X), Chrome will automatically make use of the certificate.
  - You can access your systems certificate trust store at Chrome settings > HTTPS/SSL. Or you can follow the relevant instructions for your built-in browser:
  - Windows: Internet Explorer >> [Installing Burp's CA Certificate in Internet Explorer](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783080-Installing_Installing%20CA%20Certificate%20-%20IE.html)
  - When the Burp CA certificate has been installed for your built-in browser, restart Chrome and you should be able to visit any HTTPS URL via Burp without any security warnings.
- [Internet Explorer](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1783080-Installing_Installing%20CA%20Certificate%20-%20IE.html)

  - With Burp running, visit http://burp in IE and click the "CA Certificate" link to download and save your Burp CA certificate. Take note of where you save the Burp CA certificate.
  - You will be prompted with a message, click “Save”. The file “cacert.der” should now download.
  - You will be prompted with another message, click “Open” and a “Certificate” box will pop up.
  - Click “Install Certificate”.
  - In the “Certificate Import Wizard” dialog box click “Next”.
  - In the Certificate Import Wizard, select "Place all certificates in the following store" and click “Browse”.
  - In the “Select Certificate Store” window select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and click “OK”.
  - Complete the wizard by clicking “Next” followed by “Finish”.
  - Click "Yes" on the security warning.Close all dialogs and restart IE (no need to run as administrator).
  - If everything has worked, you should now be able to visit any HTTPS URL via Burp without any security warnings.